# .NET GridView - Can you right-align just one column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Can you easily right-align just one column in a GridView?

I have this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

It is bound to a DataTable (generated dynamically) that has many columns. I just want the 'Price' column to be right-aligned.

(Coming across this problem, I am wondering if I should be printing out HTML `<table>` instead of using a GridView. Using HTML I would have total control.)

Comment: Use Right Aligned Template field for price column. possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can, but I *think* if you have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true (which it is by default) then you need to right align the column using the `RowDataBound` event. As a side note, if it's easier you can set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false and use [BoundFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx) which will give you more formatting options and will probably eliminate the need for the `RowDataBound` event.

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object o, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Assumes the Price column is at index 4
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        e.Row.Cells[4].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see... yeah as I expected it's not very pretty. AutoGenerateColumns IS the reason I use GridView. I'd rather print out HTML than using GridView with AutoGenerateColumns disabled. Thanks! That answers my question :)

Answer (score 13):

```
<Columns>
...
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" 
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
...
</Columns>
```

Comment: This will add an extra column instead of formatting the column I want

Comment: Add your columns like this in the markup. Unless you have a specific reason for wanting to do it in your code-behind?

Comment: To use this approach you would need to set AutoGenerateColumns to false and manually add in all the columns in the markup. The downside is its alot of typing. The upside is you get more control over the formatting without having to resort to the codebehind. Personally I feel that using the BoundFields is a better approach.

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns IS the reason I use GridView. I'd rather print out HTML (and have total control) than using GridView with AutoGenerateColumns disabled. What do you think?

Comment: I usually cheat by having one already set up in markup and then tweak it. As you said, more control :)

Comment: @aximili, if you want cleaner HTML, drop the GridView and go with a ListView instead. I use the ListView exclusively these days for that reason :)

Comment: Having GridView markup in another project that I can reuse :)

Comment: oh I see... may be I should try ListView, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: It will give you nice clean divs :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question posted long ago, this might help someone you happens to end up at this page.

The answers given assume that the index of the column to which the alignment will be applied is known in advance or the columns are created at design time on the .aspx page; but this is not always the case.

For someone looking for a general solution in which the **columns are auto generated** and the **index** of column with header ‘Price’ **not known in advance**, here is a solution

```
protected void grData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int i = ((DataTable)((GridView)sender).DataSource).Columns.IndexOf("Price");
        for (int j = 0; j < e.Row.Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            if (j == i)
                e.Row.Cells[j].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            else
                e.Row.Cells[j].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the item in the ItemTemplate in a div and then set styling to the div.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<div id="divReportName">
<asp:Label ID="lblReport" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>

// css for div
#divReportName { text-align: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform alignment within the Boundfield using ItemStyle-

like this :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="SOH" HeaderText="SOH" SortExpression="SOH" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
```

This worked for me where i needed to align only specific columns in my gridview

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this in the first line of the `GridView`?

```
OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```