# C# Grid column right alignment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the below code(Partial Code) to get print out of a grid rows. But the last column having the amount.So i want to align the last column as right alignment.But i got the error.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Datasource"];
DataTable newTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "FLD_ID", "FLD_CUST_ID", "FLD_CUST_NAME", "FLD_CUST_ADDR", "FLD_AMT");

newTable.Columns["FLD_ID"].ColumnName = "PAY.ID";
newTable.Columns["FLD_CUST_ID"].ColumnName = "CUST.ID";
newTable.Columns["FLD_CUST_NAME"].ColumnName = "CUST.NAME";
newTable.Columns["FLD_CUST_ADDR"].ColumnName = "ADDRESS";               
newTable.Columns["FLD_AMT"].ColumnName = "INV.AMOUNT";


GridView PrintGrid = new GridView();
PrintGrid.DataSource = newTable;
PrintGrid.DataBind();
PrintGrid.AllowPaging = false;

PrintGrid.Columns[4].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
//Got Error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index.
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET GridView - Can you right-align just one column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644097/net-gridview-can-you-right-align-just-one-column)

Comment: try to give column name instead of Columns[4]

Comment: Not Working. It only allow int.

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintGrid.Columns[4].ItemStyle.CssClass="alignright";
```

then add css

```
.alignright{
   text-align:right;
      }
```

Comment: then Columns[4] does not exists,make it Coloumns[3] and try

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution of your problem.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object o, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Assumes the Price column is at index 4
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        e.Row.Cells[4].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Align it in rowdatabound event

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object o, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way it worked for me was using

```
e.Row.Cell[field_position].Style.Value = "text-align: right".
```

Nothing more needed to work beyond this code. Works fine. Other options did not take effect even when using all together.