# How to align right dynamically created column content in a datagridview

Tags: c#, dynamic, datagridview, alignment, cell

I am developing a desktop application using Visual Studio 2013 in C#. I have a datagridview of which its some columns are created dynamically whereas some are static. I want to align my dynamically created columns content to right side of the cells. I can successfully align static columns, however `datagridview.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment` does not work for dynamically created columns. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you have a look at this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644097/net-gridview-can-you-right-align-just-one-column

Answer (score 0):

There is a property, that can be set for each column independently:

```
DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I tried for datagridview, for rows and for columns. Result is negative.

Comment: @ceskin when you say "dynamically created columns" do you mean added by calling datagridview.Columns.Add(column)? can you show the code you use to create/add columns and set content alignment?

Comment: 'tempCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

tempCol.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;

tempCol.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;

tempCol.HeaderText = index.ToString();

tempCol.Name = "Day_" + tempCol.HeaderText;

tempCol.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;

tempCol.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

tempCol.ToolTipText = tempCol.HeaderText;

tempCol.Width = 70;

dgvShift.Columns.Add(tempCol);'

Comment: @ceskin sorry I can't reproduce your issue :(